# Trying to select element based on link with class list object - beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautifulsoup 4.4 and python 3.6.6. I have extracted all the links however I cannot print out all links which contain

> 'class': ['_self']

This is the full link that is retrieved that I want to capture out of the list of links.

```
{'href': 'https://www.racingnsw.com.au/news/latest-racing-news/highway-sixtysix-on-right-route/', 'class': ['_self'], 'target': '_self'}
```

I cannot get the syntax correct although it looks like the bs4 docs on [attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes).

```
import requests as req
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = req.get(
    'https://www.racingnsw.com.au/media-news-premierships/latest-news/')

data = url.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all('a')

for item in links:
    print(item['class']='self')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeautifulSoup supports CSS selectors which allow you to select elements based on the content of particular attributes. This includes the selector *= for contains.

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = req.get(
    'https://www.racingnsw.com.au/media-news-premierships/latest-news/')

data = url.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for items in soup.select('a[class*="_self"]'):
    print(items)
```